# Virtualenv error - build_ext

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a requirements.txt file that consists of the following modules:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Login==0.3.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
SQLAlchemy==0.9.8
Werkzeug==0.9.6
argparse==1.2.1
itsdangerous==0.24
rauth==0.7.0
requests==2.4.3
```

When I activate my virtualenv to install these modules `.\venv\Scripts\activate` SQLAlchemy fails and MarkupSafe fails. If I deactivate my virtualenv, and simply `pip install MarkupSafe` or `pip install SQLAlchemy` - they successfully install.

I am at a loss as to why this is. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling virtualenv & python - and have spoken with a friend who is quite knowledgable about Python (he thought it was something specific to the Windows environment) and unfortunately am at a loss as to what to try next.

I suspect that it may have something to do with the fact that I deleted a folder named 'Python' underneath user\AppData.. in my attempts to uninstall Python and start from a clean slate...

Here is the relevant output (or at least, what I think is the relevant part of the output) associated with MarkupSafe:

```
  Running setup.py clean for SQLAlchemy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for markupsafe ... error
  Complete output from command c:\test_oauth\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SEANBA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\\markupsafe\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\
r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkf78v48_pip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5
  creating build\lib.win32-3.5\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\tests.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_constants.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\_native.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\markupsafe
  copying markupsafe\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\markupsafe
  running egg_info
  writing dependency_links to MarkupSafe.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing MarkupSafe.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to MarkupSafe.egg-info\top_level.txt
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

  reading manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'MarkupSafe.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying markupsafe\_speedups.c -> build\lib.win32-3.5\markupsafe
  running build_ext
  building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\markupsafe\setup.py", line 120, in <module>
      try_building_extension()
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\markupsafe\setup.py", line 99, in try_building_extension
      run_setup(True)
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\markupsafe\setup.py", line 93, in run_setup
      ext_modules=ext_modules,
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\test_oauth\venv\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\markupsafe\setup.py", line 41, in run
      build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 338, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 447, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 472, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\markupsafe\setup.py", line 47, in build_extension
      build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 532, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 306, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 199, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "c:\test_oauth\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 206, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_ver_min=14.0).return_env()
  TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vc_ver_min'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for markupsafe
```

Here is the relevant output (or at least, what I think is the relevant part of the output) associated with the SQLAlchemy failure:

```
  running build_ext
  building 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors' extension
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\SQLAlchemy\setup.py", line 170, in <module>
      run_setup(True)
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\SQLAlchemy\setup.py", line 150, in run_setup
      **kwargs
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\test_oauth\venv\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\SQLAlchemy\setup.py", line 67, in run
      build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 338, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 447, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 472, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\SEANBA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-pvc5zlcc\SQLAlchemy\setup.py", line 73, in build_extension
      build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 532, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 306, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "C:\Python35-32\Lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 199, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "c:\test_oauth\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 206, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_ver_min=14.0).return_env()
  TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vc_ver_min'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for SQLAlchemy
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here:  Is your venv python the same python as the python whose `pip install -r requirements.txt` works?  As in, are they both 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue.

The environment variable for python had been incorrectly configured (it had been made it's own system variable, rather than simply being added to the 'path' system variable).

Once this was changed, the issues disappeared.